# Problem creating OctoMap from PointCloud2

Tags: octomap, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to create an octomap from PointCloud2. I load the pointcloud from my ply file convert it into PointCloud2 and publish it on 'cloud_in' topic. The messages are published file. I then launch the octo map node via the launch file which is below

```
<!-- Octomap Server -->
<node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap">
    <param name="resolution" value="0.05" />

    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_link" />

    <param name="max_sensor_range" value="20.0" />

    <param name="latch" value="false" />
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="occupied_cells_vis" />

</node>
```

but unfortunately I cant see anything on Rviz MarkerArray which is listening to occupied_cells_vis.
What am I doing wrong here ????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203141/problem-creating-octomap-from-pointcloud2/) by [shehrozeb37](https://answers.ros.org/users/21638/shehrozeb37/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on 2015-02-15**:
Is the transform correct? your remap should be from="cloud_in" to=the topic you publish with the messages

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-02-17**:
can i ask you how open the ply file and convert the pointcloud publishing it in pointcloud2??

**Comment by [knightd23](https://answers.ros.org/users/23279/knightd23/) on 2015-09-03**:
I could already create octomap from pointcloud. In your line '' change the occupied_cells_vis to the output topic from your pointcloud. Make sure that your output topic of point cloud has the kind of message poincloud2 and has data in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the same problem, but instead of occupied_cells_vis I use my_cloud, which is the topic that provides the pointCloud2. What I  doing wrong?

I saw the chris_ comment and I don't know where I can put the transform, however I own the topics publish the transformation (tf and tf_static).

Best Regards

---

Originally posted by [knightd23](https://answers.ros.org/users/23279/knightd23/) with karma: 36 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0